# Create circle that is proportionately sized to window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to create a circle with a height of 10% the browser window. If I also make the width 10%, and you scale the browser, you get a misshapen or squished circle. I want to try to create the width of the circle with jquery to change in proportion with the height. so if 10% converts to 200px height, the width would be changed to 200px. I have tried a few solutions, but keep getting a width of 0px in return.

Comment: Could you please post a jsfiddle with your attempted solution?

Comment: Edit: Here is a fiddle of what I am trying to accomplish. the problem is, if you scale the window the width aspect is stuck at whatever the loaded width is, it does not adjust to the changing page size.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettlewis/MVCHN/)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using jQuery and your circle is an HTML element you could do this:

```
var $window = $(window),
    $el = $('#someElement');

$window.on('resize', function () {

    var size = $window.height() * 0.1;
    $el.width(size).height(size);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the width and the height of the window and then simply check which one of them is the smallest. Get 10% of that value and use this as the circle's radius.

Answer (score 0):

Little experiment using a transparent square image which is the direct child of `<body>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/2S3xU/3/

```
<html><body><img src="transparent-square.gif">

img {
    border-radius: 99999px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height:     100%; /* width will follow height to keep image undistorted*/
    max-width:  100%;
    max-height: 10%;
}​

/* Opera fix*/
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```